# IE9 "Access is Denied" with dojo.io.iframe, but only when following a gmail link

Tags: iframe, file-upload, dojo, internet-explorer-9, access-denied

Okay, we're using dojo.io.iframe to upload a file. I've been reading about the many different ways the situation can get "access is denied" errors, but I'm still stumped. Here are some details:

- dojo 1.6.1 (23843)
- IE 9.0.8112.16421 on Windows 7
- **Strangest part:** To get to the upload page, the user clicks a link in an email. I get the error when I open gmail in IE and click the link then submit the form, but it doesn't happen if I copy and paste the link into IE and submit the form.
- Nothing cross domain. However the address is an ip address, not a hostname or domain name.
- The error happens on the form.submit() line in the dojo.io.iframe _fireNextRequest() function. So it can't be caused by anything in the response from the server.

This exact same code works just fine in IE on other pages and when I copy and paste the link instead of following it through gmail.

Comment: Similar issue here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/457

Comment: No clear answers, but it seems like other people around the web are encountering this: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443991/why-form-submit-is-fails-ie9-when-form-in-iframe-and-user-coming-through-gma) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980103/script5-access-denied-in-ie9-in-same-domain)

Comment: [three](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/lt-apex-inputFile-gt-problem-on-IE-9-and-Sites/td-p/495857)